# How to flip/switch Dashing widget on click

Tags: dashing

I have seen this done on several web pages (for example fitbit) where a widget is flipped to display new information when it is clicked.

I was wondering whether anyone could give me some help on how to achieve this or provide a code sample of it.

Thank you for any help or tips.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it setting an attribute on your widget's Coffescript starting it with `false` and bind a toggle function using `data-event-click` on your view. That will toggle the value of your attribute. 
Them, you put what you want to show and hide on two containers and bind that attribute on them, using `data-hideif='attributeName'` on the container you want to hide when raise a click event on your widget and using `data-showif='attributeName'` on the container you want to show when raise the click event.

So, your coffescript would become something like:

```
class Dashing.ToggleableWidget extends Dashing.Widget
  toggleDetails: -> 
    @set('showDetails', !@showDetails)

# you could still use accessor with:
# @accessor 'toggleDetails',
#   get: -> @set('showDetails', !@showDetails)
#   cache: false 
# 
# ... but it is not necessary, and using a normal function will solve your problem

  ready: -> 
    @showDetails = false
```

And your view would become something like:

```
<div class="status-accounts" data-event-click="toggleDetails">
  <div class="summary" data-hideif="showDetails" data-bind="summary"></div>
  <div class="details" data-showif="showDetails">
    <div class="account" data-foreach-account='accounts' data-bind-title='account.status'>
      <span class="name" data-bind="account.account_name | append ' - '"></span>
      <span class="status" data-bind="account.status | truncate 3, ''"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With that, when your widget be rendered (or re-rendered after changing data), it will show your summary container, and if you click, it will show your details container.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it helped me greatly.  I have one issue and one question though. I have used more or less exactly the code you gave me (without the account stuff) and the first "page" does not re-render when I click the widget again. It seems like it should since showDetails should be false again when the widget has been clicked twice.
Also is there a way to differentiate between a drag and a click so that the on click method does not activate when the widget is dragged to another position?

Comment: Ok it seems like the toggle details function only triggers once...Why is this?

Comment: I think that I misunderstood the accessor behaviour. Or at least his default behaviour, because it has a cache that when you bind accessors with data-bind, it prevents to re-execute every time and executes once until some of theirs variables changes (at least when you call that attributes with @get). That cache can be disabled, but on your case it would be better implement the function as a normal function. I 'm gonna edit my answer for that.